# Using the string value as the property of an object to find the property's returned value

Tags: javascript, string, object, properties

I come from the Ruby world. How do I use the string value of an array as a property of an object? Example ..

```
obj.myarray[0] = 1.00 // obviously this does not work, can you pro make it work?

obj = {
 val1: 1.00, val2: 2.00}

myarray = ["val1"]
```

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking. Can you explain what feature that's in Ruby that you're looking for in JavaScript? Do you mean accessing a property of an object while you have the property name as a string?

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking from what you've written.

Comment: @AtesGoral Yep, looks like he has the name of a property stored as a string in an array. He then wants to use the string value from the array to access the object's property.

Comment: This is typical of the Javascript community. Ask a question, it gets voted down. You guys should learn ruby, and you will find a much more friendly community

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer:** I believe the syntax you are looking for is this:

```
obj[myarray[0]] = 1.00;
```

This assumes you have an array, `myarray`, and the first item in the array (index 0) has the name of the key you want to use with your `obj` object.

Note that `= 1.00` is an *assignment*, so it will store that value in your object. For comparison you want the [`==` or `===` operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators).

**Long answer:**

The code from your question:

```
obj = {
   val1: 1.00, val2: 2.00}
```

creates an object called `obj` with two properties named `val1` and `val2`. These properties can be accessed like this:

```
obj["val1"]
// OR
obj.val1
```

Where the dot syntax only works with property names that follow the rules for JavaScript identifier names. With the bracket and string syntax you can use just about any string as a property name.

Then

```
myarray = ["val1"]
```

Creates an array with one element, the string "val1". So as in my "short answer", to access a property of the object using an element from the array you say:

```
obj[ myarray[0] ]
```

(Where the index, 0, can be another variable if desired.)

You might like to read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects (Also, note that in JavaScript arrays are a special type of object intended to be used with numeric indices that does not really correspond directly with the "associative arrays" of other languages - a "plain" JS object is closer to an "associative array".)

Note also that the values you are storing, `1.00` and `2.00`, being numeric, will be returned as simply `1` and `2` - if you need to retain trailing zeros after the decimal point you'll need to store them as strings.

Comment: +1 For figuring out the intent of the original question. I'm deleting my own answer that was a near miss.

Comment: Came here with different question, but your answer helped me too. Thank you. ^_^